# Sorting with BlackBerry

Tags: sorting, blackberry, java-me

I have a file consisting of entries like  Paula 100, Steve 150, Julian 200. I want to sort this.

Can I use the Collections framework in BlackBerry to sort file entries consisting of numbers and names?  I can't find any sorting program for blackberry. So I am wondering if I can use Collections.sort()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sortable collections in the BlackBerry API that you can use.  Search the JavaDocs for things like SimpleSortingVector and BigVector.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, BlackBerry uses J2ME which doesn't include the Collections framework.  However, you can still do sorting of Arrays using the [Arrays](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it. It's not specifically a Blackberry thing; it's just generic Java.

You may wish to use the version that takes a Comparator, and implement that interface so that it orders your list items in the way you wish to sort them.

Comment: See Marc's answer: standard Java Collections is not available in J2ME.

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed true; misremembered, sorry about that.