# blackberry reading a text file and updating after sort

Tags: blackberry

I am successfully able to read and print the contents of a text file. My text file contains 5 data entries such as

```
Rashmi 120
Prema 900
```

It must sort only the integers in descending order and swap the respective names attached to them. the first column of serial number must remain the same. Each time a new entry is made that score must be compared to the existing 5 records and placed accordingly with new name and score.

Since this is blackberry programming and blackberry APIs don't support Collections.sort,please tell me how do I do this. I tried using [SimpleSortingVector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/SimpleSortingVector.html) but I am unable to put it into coding form.

Comment: Is this some sort of homework problem?   There is an identical question with a nearly identical sorting specification already on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069579/sorting-with-blackberry

Comment: its not a homework problem Michael. I am a blackberry developer.Just kicked off with this last month. I happened to visit the link you mentioned above. That guy also has the same problem. But no solutions. So please don't mind if people post in similar questions. Its indicates they haven't got a solution for it. Since blackberry has limited APIs programming has become a headache

Answer (score 0):

i believe u need to start with your own logic like

1) sorting depends on comparison
2) before making any comparison u need to split each string by spaces
3) after splitting save the name and numbers in different arrays
4) compare the numbers and accordingly do sorting 
5) after this merge the array contents using indexing

m just giving u a way may be its not the perfect but drilling down may refine logics and usage of the api